# Error with Symfony The option "constraints" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony question, I'm just starting to learn it.
The user uploads a file with data that I want to submit to the form for validation in the form of an array (key-value). I call the method to build the form, pass an array there and try to check, for example, that the length of the title ('title') is no more than 255 characters. The error "The option "constraints" does not exist" is thrown.

*ImportService.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use App\Entity\Import;  
use App\Service\ServiceInterface;  
use Box\Spout\Reader\Common\Creator\ReaderEntityFactory;  
use Symfony\Component\Form\Forms;  
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry; 
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;

class ImportService implements ServiceInterface {
    public function __construct(protected ManagerRegistry $doctrine)
    {
    }
 
    public function parse(Import $import, array $scheme, array $formOptions = [])
    {
        $rowArray = [];

        $reader = ReaderEntityFactory::createXLSXReader();
        $reader->open($import->getPath());
        foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $index => $sheet) {
            foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $rowIndex => $row) {
                if ($rowIndex == 1) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    $cells = $row->getCells();
                    foreach ($cells as $cell) {
                        $rowArray[] = $cell->getValue();
                    };

                    $row = array_combine($scheme, $rowArray);

                    $importRow = new ImportRow($import, $sheet, $rowIndex, $row);

                    $form = $this->buildForm($import->getFormType());
                    $form->submit($row);

                    if ($form->isValid()) {
                        $import->setSuccess('true');
                        $this->saveImport($import);

                        return $row;
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }

    protected function buildForm(string $formType, array $formOptions = []): Form
    {
        $formFactory = Forms::createFormFactory();

        return $formFactory
            ->create(
                $formType,
                null,

            );
    }
```

*NewsImportType.php*

```
use App\Entity\News; use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;  
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;  
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;  
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType; 
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType; 
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection; 
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email; 
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length; 
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Url;

class NewsImportType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, [
                'constraints' =>
                [new Length(['max' => 256])],
            ])
            ->add('text', TextareaType::class, [
                'constraints' =>
                [new Length(['max' => 1000])],
            ])
            ->add('image', TextType::class, [
                'constraints' =>
                [
                    new Length(['max' => 256]),
                    new Url()
                ],
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'allow_extra_fields' => true,
            'data_class' => News::class,
        ]);
    } }
```

*Error text*

> An error has occurred resolving the options of the form
> "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType": The option
> "constraints" does not exist. Defined options are: "action",
> "allow_file_upload", "attr", "attr_translation_parameters",
> "auto_initialize", "block_name", "block_prefix", "by_reference",
> "compound", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data",
> "error_bubbling", "form_attr", "getter", "help", "help_attr",
> "help_html", "help_translation_parameters", "inherit_data",
> "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "is_empty_callback",
> "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "label_html",
> "label_translation_parameters", "mapped", "method",
> "post_max_size_message", "priority", "property_path", "required",
> "row_attr", "setter", "translation_domain", "trim",
> "upload_max_size_message".

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION**

Add 'FormFactoryInterface $formFactory' to the constructor.
And in the method itself, fix to '$this->'

```
return $this->formFactory
            ->create(
                $formType,
                null,
                array_merge($formOptions, $baseOptions)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `constraints` option is part of `ValidatorExtension` and it is not part of core form extensions. You can use it like following

```
$validator = Validation::createValidator();
$formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
        ->addExtension(new ValidatorExtension($validator))
        ->getFormFactory();
```

also add this

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\ValidatorExtension;
```

[refer link for details](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html)

Comment: Thank you! It works!!)

Comment: Welcome. Glad I could help you!

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#constraints):

> This option is added in the [FormTypeValidatorExtension](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.0/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Validator/Type/FormTypeValidatorExtension.php) form extension.

You probably forgot to install the [Validator component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html):

```sh
composer require symfony/validator
```

Comment: No, it's been installed(

Answer (score 0):

Acoordind to the doc, you mush have something like that :

```php
->add('title', TextType::class, [
                'constraints' =>
                new Length(['max' => 256]),
            ])
            ->add('text', TextareaType::class, [
                'constraints' =>
                new Length(['max' => 1000]),
            ])
            ->add('image', TextType::class, [
                'constraints' =>
                [
                    new Length(['max' => 256]),
                    new Url()
                ],
            ]);
```

You put this :

```
'constraints' =>
                [new Length(['max' => 256])],
            ])
```

the doc say this :

```
 'constraints' => new Length(['max' => 256]),
```

Comment: Changed, but the error remains